# How did They Do this? UINavigation with Toolbar on transparent

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm just new to the ipad development world, and have come across the Instapaper app, and I just love the UI on this app.

Specifically, [alt text http://sbox.smokingapples.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/instapaper.jpg](http://sbox.smokingapples.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/instapaper.jpg)

Can you tell me what techniques would be used in creating a Navigation Controller with toolbar items, all on a transparent background?

***How did they do it?***

This seems like a common pattern in iPad apps, but I don't see any code examples in the apple developer site that gives hints on how this effect is achieved.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide your own implementation of `-drawRect:` in your navigation bar subclass, that doesn't draw a background image.

Comment: Thanks Graham, and do you think they would be just using the standard UINavigationController, or rolled their own?  I didn't think you could do the toolbars on the NavigationBar like that with items on the right and left of the title as well.